# Can you experiment on a live node.js site without crashing server?

Tags: node.js

I have a live website running a node.js express application listening to port 80.  Is there a way to easily experiment with other node apps on the same server without causing it to crash every time I have a bug?

I'm new to learning Node, so my apologies for the dumb question.  I'm more experienced with working with .php where if I want to experiment with MySQL queries or something I just create a new directory and crash over and over until I figure out the solution and it doesn't affect the rest of the website.

Comment: Yes, every node process is independent from the other. (i.e. if you run `node foo.js` and `node bar.js` and the latter crashes it won't affect the former).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, one process should be insulated from another process so one node.js app should be insulated from another node.js process and no amount of crashing one node.js process should bother the other.

But, there are other bad things you can do to a server that could affect the live node.js site.

For example, a simple infinite loop on a single CPU server could starve the CPU cycles enough to prevent normal operation of your other node.js site.

A really heinous bug could cause the OS itself to crash (not so likely, but not unheard of).

A bug that accidentally consumes all disk space or all memory could starve the system enough to affect your live site.

Hosting services that wish to share hardware between clients with the least chance of one client impacting another will put each client in a VM and set up parameters that prevent one from stealing too many resources to overly affect the other.

But, the safe way to do this is to use a different host for most testing and only do final testing of what you believe is a ready-to-deploy second app on your live server.